# Adding a date range of +5 days to variable in query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is what I am trying to do.

I want to take a date of mine for example. `2013-03-13` and from that date I want to search a column in my table, BUT..I only want to search for dates that have 5 days or greater between my variable (above) and the date I am searching.

So if I run into `2013-03-10`, then that would not be valid, but if I ran into `2013-03-08` then it would be valid on my query because it is five days or greater out from my `$setupStart` variable. How would I put that in a query? I just want to make sure there is five days before my setupStart date when I search the `ts_inventory`.`Date` column and the quantity column.

Here is my query so far.

```
$setupStart = 2013-03-13;

SELECT * FROM `ts_inventory` WHERE `ts_inventory`.`Quantity` > 0 AND '$setupStart'
```

EDIT:
I am getting close..here is my query now, but dates in April aren't showing up for some reason. It is adding 5 days though to the dates in the column it goes through and then checks to see if its less then the setupStart.

EDIT:

The query does actually work. I'll post complete query below.

```
SELECT * FROM `ts_inventory` WHERE `ts_inventory`.`Quantity` > 0 AND `ts_inventory`.`LastDate` + INTERVAL 5 DAY <= '2013-03-13'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ts_inventory` 
WHERE `ts_inventory`.`Quantity` > 0 
AND datefield BETWEEN '$setupStart' AND '$setupStart' + INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

Comment: I have a particular column with several dates John Conde. I should modify my question.

Comment: Its modified now. I am searching dates and from those dates I want to make sure there is a buffer of 5 days between my var and the dates I am searching.

Comment: Any ideas guys? I am trying to find an answer, but no luck so far.

Comment: That selects one date only in my query. I need to have the datefield be greater or equal then five days out from the variable. If its less then 5, then no go.

Comment: It looks like the OP wants _previous_ days (admittedly, the language used is a little obtuse).  Also, please never use `BETWEEN`, especially when dealing with date/time

Comment: Trying my best to explain. Sorry for the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do a few steps here.

1. Take the dates in the table and add 5 days to each date.
2. Then I took that result and made sure it was less then or equal to my start date.
3. Finally got it to work! Code is below.

   SELECT * FROM `ts_inventory` WHERE `ts_inventory`.`Quantity` > 0 AND `ts_inventory`.`LastDate` + INTERVAL 5 DAY <= '$setupStart'